# How to check empty condition for an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have an object like below but i am not sure how to check the empty condition
My object,

```
 "general_info" : {
    "parents_name" : "",
    "date_of_birth" : "",
    "second_day_attendance" : "",
    "class_day" : "",
    "reffered_by" : "",
    "year" : "",
    "amount_paid" : "",
    "next_due" : "",
    "payment_untill" : "",
    "payment_made" : ""
},

    if(general_info == ''){
      alert('empty')
    }
```

I know i am wrong can any one help me.Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to check if all the properties are empty?

Answer (score 2):

If the ultimate aim is to check if all property-values are empty strings:

```
// retrieve an Array of the keys of the named Object:
Object.keys(general_info)
  // iterate over all the keys in the Array, using
  // Array.prototype.every() to see if all keys
  // match the supplied assessment:
  .every(
    // using an Arrow function to see if the current
    // property-value of the named key of the Object
    // is equal to a zero-length String:
    key => general_info[key] === ''
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for length using [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
Object.keys(general_info).length
// 10
```

```js
var general_info = {
    "parents_name" : "",
    "date_of_birth" : "",
    "second_day_attendance" : "",
    "class_day" : "",
    "reffered_by" : "",
    "year" : "",
    "amount_paid" : "",
    "next_due" : "",
    "payment_untill" : "",
    "payment_made" : ""
};

if(Object.keys(general_info).length > 0){
   console.log('Object is not empty');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to check the existance of properties on an object.

```
!Object.keys(obj).length
```

```js
const general_info = {
  "parents_name": "",
  "payment_made": ""
}

const empty_object = {}

function isEmpty(obj) {
  return !Object.keys(obj).length
}

console.log(
  isEmpty(general_info)
)
console.log(
  isEmpty(empty_object) 
)
```